# CoreData NSPredicate on a Transformable causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, transformable

What is the correct way to search for existence of an array element in a `Transformable` in Core Data using `NSPredicate`?

I have an `Entity` with an `Attribute` operationalDays with a `Type` of `Transformable` which is set given a `Custom Class [Int]`. 
[image]
I use it to store, well Arrays of Ints. It works to store but I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to fetch them using an NSPredicate

I Know

> operationalDays is {1,2,3,4}

I am trying but they all fail with error.

```
//day is an Int (1) in this case

NSPredicate(format: "%d IN operationalDays",day) 
NSPredicate(format: "%i IN operationalDays",day) 
NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN operationalDays",day) 
NSPredicate(format: "operationalDays CONTAINS %d",day) 
NSPredicate(format: "operationalDays CONTAINS %i",day)
NSPredicate(format: "operationalDays CONTAINS %@",day)
```

when I inspect the predicate after crash I get

> predicate: (1 IN operationalDays);

or

> predicate: (operationalDays CONTAINS 1)

Comment: Not sure I remember this correctly but if I do then transformable are actually binary data which may be serialized so in your case are most likely represented by some XML like format which has enough information to reconstruct back your array. But as far as database goes these are raw binary data and you may not use predicates on them. If possible try adding another string field in which you do the search. When saving your entity construct this string from all the fields you want to search from.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I’m thinking to do. Just hoped there be some magic written into Swift to handle such NSPredicates

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `NSPredicate` simply the SQL query fails. But again, I am not 100% sure in any of these so maybe someone comes with a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transformable attributes are stored as binary data in the Sqlite DB. You can't run a query on that data unless your predicate has binary data as well. Transformable attributes abide by NSCoding protocol, hence, Core Data knows how to serialize and deserialize the attribute.

P.S. To see the error that Sqlite throws, try adding

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

to the "Arguments Passed on Launch" in your Xcode scheme.

[image]

Comment: At a loss on how to do this. Do I add -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug and set its value to 1 ?

Comment: I've added the picture so that it's more clear. And you may mark this answer as correct if it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

you should use the predicate in this style

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN days", argumentArray: [valueOfArgumentHere])
```